# Install LVM after Ubuntu is already installed

Tags: lvm

Is it possible to install LVM after Ubuntu is already installed?  Running version 16.04.  The server is already in production with production data so a reformat is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Open ubuntu..search for LVM and install the logical management tool.Or run the sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm in a command window.Open lvm from the dash once its done.